# Searching a HashByte column in MSSQL

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to search a MSSQL Table which contains user data. The two columns I am most interested in is username, and password. The password column is a binary(20) datatype and contains data generated by

```
   HashBytes('SHA1','Password')
```

This is the call I'm making, without success. What am I missing?

```
$select_user=sqlsrv_prepare($connection,"
    SELECT
         id, username
    FROM
         dbo.users
    WHERE
         username=? AND password=HashBytes('SHA1',?)",
    array(&$username, &$password));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in your post to indicate that you are doing anything that would prevent your query from working.

```
CREATE TABLE T (
  usr VARCHAR(100),
  pwd BINARY(20)
  );

INSERT INTO T
   (usr, pwd)
  VALUES
   ('john', HashBytes('SHA1', 'john-pwd'))

INSERT INTO T
   (usr, pwd)
  VALUES
   ('jane', HashBytes('SHA1', 'jane-pwd'))
```

And here would be a sample query:

```
DECLARE @pwd AS VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @usr AS VARCHAR(100)

SET @usr = 'john'
SET @pwd = 'john-pwd'

-- search for john's record by username & password
SELECT *
  FROM T
 WHERE usr = @usr
   AND pwd = HashBytes('SHA1', @pwd)
```

Here is a SQL Fiddle link that shows a working sample: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/45766/2/0

```
usr   | pwd
------+----------------------------------------
john  | kwRrA4hNLaWscG4RJMRy/9k43sM=
```

You could probably cache the hashed password for the query but besides that the query should work just fine.

Comment: would it be something having to do with the sqlsrv_prepare? I just thought I would simplify the question, but I edited to the actual PHP statements.

Comment: it shouldn't. have you verified that the query works with hard-coded values? That's what I would try first.